# configure aws to allow jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I've developed a MVC web application that uses jquery to send and receive data from the server.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.visibility != "hidden") {
        toggle();
        var organismo = jQuery('input[name=radios]:checked').val();

        //first get all parameters if any
        var param1 = $('#p1').val(),
        param2 = $('#p2').val(),
        param3 = $('#p3').val(),
        param4 = $('#p4').val(),
        param5 = $('#a1').val(),
        param6 = $('#a2').val(),
        param7 = $('#a3').val(),
        param8 = $('#a4').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../prescavi/comparar",
            data: "{presc1:'" + param1 + "', aviad1:'" + param5 + "',presc2:'" + param2 + "', aviad2:'" + param6 + "', presc3:'" + param3 + "', aviad3:'" + param7 + "', presc4:'" + param4 + "', aviad4:'" + param8 + "'}",
            success: function (blue) {
                debugger
                if (blue != null) {
                    if (blue.length > 0) {
                        var labeltotal = (blue[0][1]);
                        if ((blue[0][1]) == "l") {
                            labeltotal = (blue[0][1]).toUpperCase();
                        }
                        $('#labeltotal0').html(labeltotal);
                        tooltipalinea("labeltotal0", (blue[0][1]));
```

and so forth, and the function returns this:

```
<HttpPost>
   Function mostrar(receita As Object, rlinha1 As Object, rlinha2 As Object, rlinha3 As Object, rlinha4 As Object, medsp1 As Object, medsp2 As Object, medsp3 As Object, medsp4 As Object, medsa1 As Object, medsa2 As Object, medsa3 As Object, medsa4 As Object) As ActionResult

   Dim lst() As Object = {receita, rlinha1, rlinha2, rlinha3, rlinha4, medsp1, medsp2, medsp3, medsp4, medsa1, medsa2, medsa3, medsa4}  

   Return Me.Json(lst.ToArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

   Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Input")

   End Function
```

I had it in Azure and it worked perfectly.
Now I've deployed to Amazon (AWS EC2) because it is free.

But now the jquery doesn't return data.

I use 2 databases on the application. I opened the ports for them. One for login and it is working. The other is the real database where functions go fetch data to return and in VS the connection is working perfectly. So it must be a java problem.

Do I need to open any specific port for this or tweek any configuration?

Thanks

Comment: try adding  traditional:true in ajax call

Comment: To check if it port issue add All TCP 0.0.0.0/0 rule in security group and check if works if it works then it is port issue if not then you can rule out the port issue.

Comment: Lots of missing details. What kind of database? Where is the database server (Azure, AWS, your own network)? What service were you using on Azure before?

Comment: Thank you all.
It's nothing to do with javascript or ports.
Apparently I need to rebuild the dataset. Something is not right there. It was but no longer is.